# How to draw a rotational symmetric surface using opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

So I am working on an optical lens simulation software where I was asked to create an API that takes in the 2D cross-section of the lens and draw it in 3D. The schematic looks like this:
[image: Surface with rotational symmetry]

The idea is to have a set of points as input describing the 2D cross-section, then render a 3D surface on the window using opengl(c++).

One method I can think of is to generate 3D vertices, indices and normals data in c++ code and feed them to the vertex/fragment shader.

Then I come across the tessellation and geometry shaders during my research, where one can actually draw a curve or even a surface using control points. I'm not familiar with tessellation and geometry shaders, can you guys give me an insight about how I can use them to draw rotational symmetry surfaces?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read about [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask),  and [ask] a good question.

Comment: You can start looking at [solid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution)

Comment: If you don't need particularly high performance nor high detail (as in hundreds of frames per second, or hundreds of thousands of triangles) then just do it in C++ code (on the CPU), because it's *easier*.

Comment: It is unclear do you want to opengl draw 2D or 3D images. If 2D, you probably don't need opengl, but if you need 3D, forget tesselation and geometry shaders at this point. Use only vertex and fragment shaders and once that works, and you want to increase quality, then add tesselation.